# Upload a photo to another domain

Tags: php, html, curl

I have a number of different domains where I would like users to be able to select a photo, however I want to photos uploaded/stored on one central separated domain.

Is there a more advisable way to do this?

I've considered using an iframe from the other domain (so they are interacting with the required domain) but haven't tried it yet.

I have also read that curl can potentially do this.

Any other ideas/problems/concerns...

All advise appreciated.

thx

Comment: "central separated domain", love it

Comment: you know an img src can be a full url pointing to any domain on the web

Comment: sure I know that. I just don't want images scatter across lots of domains as I will have a number of upload domains. Would like them all to reside on one domain/folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can handle this. Here are the scenarios I see.

Scenario A:
All domains are on the same server. With this setup you can actually help your server security by storing the images and other files in a directory that is not accessible by Apache. Then you use PHP to serve the file to the end user through virtual links. Drupal does this with its private file system.

If the users are able to upload images from the other domains then just have all of the domains write the images to the same directory, but then always return the "central" domain's URL for retrieving them.

Scenario B:
The domains exist across two or more servers. With this setup what you really need to do is setup an API where the other domains communicate behind the scenes to send the photo to the core repository domain. This domain saves it and returns a URL for accessing it.

In either case you should really look up CDN technology. Its basically what your trying to accomplish plus a lot more. I would also recommend that in either scenario that you always use the path on the central domain for all the images instead of returning them back through the current domain.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to get iframes or curl involved. Assuming that all these domains are on the same server (or same cluster of servers), there is nothing which requires that a file uploaded using a file on one domain must only be served from that domain. An upload form can do whatever it wants with the uploaded file, including storing it in a location where it'll be available from your central domain.

Comment: I'm paying for hosting and don't have control at that level. Also the provider could move things around if they need to and this could possibly break this solution. Good idea if I owned or control the webserver...